# migrating Microsoft apps from windows 2003 server to windows 2012 server

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp-classic, migration

we have more than 30 classic asp and .net applications to be migrated to windows 2012 server from 2003 server.This is new task for me, so what are the steps/factors i need to consider or fulfill for this migration? with that I mean like there are COM objects, dependent dll's all stuff so what things I should ensure are in place for smooth migration.

Microsoft provides ACT tool for Application Compatibility test how much will that support? or are there any other better proven tools for the same purpose?

any insight/help would be appreciative.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to assess is "what works and what doesn't work". There's a high chance that many of these apps will just work. That's the first thing to go do. Start by coming up with some test criteria by which the program is expected to work. Then deploy to the new OS.

One problematic area might be that these executable program require an older version of .NET or the MSVCRT DLLs that might not be on the box by default. The MSVCRT redist is easily available from Micrsoft's web site. You can install older versions of .NET from Control Panel->Programs and Features->"Turn Windows features on or off". Look for the ".NET" checkboxes near the top.

For classic ASP applications, same thing in the "Turn Windows features on or off". Look at "World Wide Web Services" node and make sure ASP (and most all of those other features) is selected.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft provides ACT tool for Application Compatibility test how much will that support? or are there any other better proven tools for the same purpose?

In my experience with automation tools, *especially* when working with older sets of technology (like classic asp)they rarely work near as well as advertised.